# t.Uploadbox.Locale[this.model.locale] is undefined

Tags: syncfusion

im trying to implement the drag and drop control

```
<div class="frame">
<div class="control">
    @Html.EJ().Uploadbox("Draganddrop").SaveUrl(@Url.Action("SaveDraganddrop")).RemoveUrl(@Url.Action("RemoveDraganddrop")).AllowDragAndDrop(true).MultipleFilesSelection(true).DropAreaHeight("300px").DropAreaWidth("600px").Locale("es-ES")
</div>
```

but this error pops all the time:

```
t.Uploadbox.Locale[this.model.locale] is undefined
```

Edit:
Screenshot of the error: [image]

Edit2:
Finaly found a solution.
If you have the same error as me, open "ej.web.all.min.js" and change 
this:

```
t.Uploadbox.Locale[this.model.locale]
```

to this:

```
t.Uploadbox.Locale["es-ES"]
```

*you can use any location you want

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have missed to include "es-ES" localization file. So please refer this file in your application like below.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ej/l10n/ej.localetexts.es-ES.min.js"></script>
```

Please refer the script in the head tag of the layout page.

*Note:- You can find the locale text file in installation location (C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\16.1.0.24\JavaScript\assets\scripts\l10n)*

Comment: Still dont work, it only happens when "AllowDragAndDrop(true)" is set.